# What are AMT sessions used for?

Tags: powershell, intel-amt

I'm familiar with Powershell sessions (ie Enter-PSSession) and what they can be used for.  I'm attempting to remotely manage power through vPro, so I've been messing around with the IntelvPro module in Powershell.  Up until now, whenever I run a command like

```
Invoke-AMTPowerManagement 72.233.143.122 -operation PowerOff
```

...it returns:

```
ComputerName        Port      Operation      Status
------------        ----      ---------      ------
72.233.143.122      16992     PowerOff       Failed
```

Basically, everything I try to do which deals with AMT fails.  However, I recently realized that I could successfully enter AMT sessions with remote machines through the commands

```
$connection = New-AMTConnection 72.233.143.122
Enter-AMTSession $connection
```

This is all well and good, but now that I'm connected to the remote machine, I'm not sure what I can do.  Ultimately I would like to remotely manage power (more specifically, reboot), and feed text to the computer via the SOL channel.

Comment: After the fail do `$error[0]` and see the reason. Usually it's permissions related but not always.

Comment: Did `$error[0]` give you any information?

Comment: I won't be able to test this until Wednesday night.  I'll let you know.

Comment: [Here](http://i.imgur.com/JzvIHCz.png)'s a screenshot of the error dump

Comment: Note, though, that the error only happens when I use `Invoke-AMTPowerManagement`.  The posted question was asking about the AMT sessions, which are different, although related.